# tooltip for html.RouteLink

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html.actionlink, routelink

is it possible to write tooltip for `html.RouteLink`?

my link:

```
 <%= Html.RouteLink("<", new { page = (Model.PageIndex - 1)},null)%>
```

Thank and take care,
Ragims

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If by 'tooltip' you mean a `title` attribute, then yes:

```
<%= Html.RouteLink("<", new { page = (Model.PageIndex - 1)}, new { title="My Tooltip" })%>
```

Comment: if i do it like you say im getting always red underline (some kind of error) of all my control.

Comment: yes your solution is right, it needed just remove null. then works.

<%= Html.RouteLink("<", new { page = (Model.PageIndex - 1)}, new { title="My Tooltip" })%>

Comment: +1 thank you. Adding html is not so obvious! I thought I should be `"title=xxxx"`